# receiving android POST data with php

Tags: php, android, post

I have searched for some answers but I cannot find anything. So how do you use PHP  to receive and save the data sent to it using POST from an android app. I am currently using the following code so what PHP would I use to store the data. Any link on tutorials for this would also be helpful.

```
public void send(View v)
 {
    // get the message from the message text box
    String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();  

    // make sure the fields are not empty
    if (msg.length()>0)
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://kiwigaming.beastnode.net/upload.php");
     try {
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", "Unitnumber"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Doneornot", msg));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       httpclient.execute(httppost);
       msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     }

    }
    else
    {
        // display message if text fields are empty
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The superglobal `$_POST` contains the post data.

```
<?php
     print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: so in what way would that save the data? explane a little please?

Comment: To access your `Date` variable for example, in your PHP script, you'd have `$_POST['Date']`. About saving it, that's quite broad. You can save into a database or a flat file, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the response first by replacing:

```
httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

with:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Then from that you can go

```
Head[] head = response.getHeaders();
for(int i = 0, i < head.length; i++){
    //find header?
}
```

or get the content?

```
String content = response.getEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: The OP's question is how to receive POST data in PHP.

Comment: Sorry I may have not made the question very clear but I need the php code for organizing and saving the data on the server

Comment: Ahh sorry, thought you wanted the Android side

Comment: No problem :) Android is kinda my thing, it was refreshing my memory anyway